# Mounting UDF hard drive partition at boot

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, udf

How do I get a UDF hard drive partition to mount at boot? From what I can figure, mountall runs before the udf module loads.

Specifically: do PREREQ specifications in initramfs-tools hooks only specify other hooks, or can they specify modules without hooks files? If the answer to this is that they can specify modules I think the solution to the greater problem will be to add a conditional PREREQ to hooks/mountall of udf if the udf module is available.

Currently I have a UDF partition on my hard drive specified in /etc/fstab, and boot hangs with "drive not yet ready or not present".  If I specify "nobootfail" in /etc/fstab, the boot completes without mounting the partition.  Since the end goal is to have the UDF partition be /home, this is a problem...

Comment: `UDF` filesystems is compatible for `fstab` settings, AFAIK. Can you make sure you edited `fstab` correctly. Might as well add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the base problem and a workaround. The problem is that the udf kernel module will not load during the initramfs phase of boot (it's supposed to even by default but doesn't even if explicitly specified); the workaround is to specify option _netdev on the udf filesystem line in fstab.

Comment: It would have been very helpful to just post your fstab for future visitors (me).  Instead of deciphering what you're talking about, I guess I'll just go to the next Google result.

Comment: Well, I've basically stopped using udf since then, but here's the basic syntax:
/dev/udf  /mountpoint  udf  defaults,_netdev  0  0